# Asp.net Web Service Test Error

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, exception

I'm just stuck within ASP.NET, I've created a Unit Test Class for test a blank Web Service (want to do TDD).

When I try to run the Web Service, it supposed to run and fail, but it fail to execute, it says:

The test adapter 'WebHostAdapter' threw an exception while running test 'EnrollmentWSConstructorTest'. The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:1032/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this link:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NUnitUnitTestingOfASPNETPagesBaseClassesControlsAndOtherWidgetryUsingCassiniASPNETWebMatrixVisualStudioWebDeveloper.aspx

I found it very helpful when I was on a project that wanted to add after-the-fact unit tests for web services, so spinning up instances of a web server were needed for testing.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't contain any information related to this specific question.

Comment: Sorry, reread your question and I gather you are using the built-in tests in Visual Studio instead of NUnit. In that case, have you altered your web.config to allow unauthenticated access to VSEnterpriseHelper.axd?

Comment: Well. I try (using the localization snippet) but it doesn't work.

Is NUnit simpler than the testing tools that come with VS2010. I came from Java world so have more experience by using JUnit.

Comment: You might find NUnit more familiar then. It would allow you to test the features of your service as a plain class without having to support the web service feature set. And if you found that you did need to support/test it as a web service, then you can use the original link I provided as guidance.

Answer (score 0):

For us I fixed this by opening the web.config of the site and changing this

```
<modules>
  <add name="HostAdapter" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapter.Web.HttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>
```

to this

```
<modules>
</modules>
```

or basically deleting the hostadapter module ... because visual studio will just automatically add it back anyways later